# PDU: SMS-DELIVER direct from a GSM Modem

Tags: sms, gsm

My understanding of the SMS-DELIVER/SMS-SUBMIT is that when Bob wants to send a text on the GSM the following happens...

Bob submits a request to send a short message to a short message service center (SMSC) in the PDU format with the SMS-SUBMIT flag set.  The service center then sends a PDU format message with the SMS-DELIVER to Alice.

Is there any way to cut out the middleman and send a direct SMS-DELIVER from one gsm phone or modem to another with no SMSC in between?